# Is My Harddrive Garbage?

Tags: windows-8, hard-drive, ssd

I have a WD Caviar Blue 1TB, I wanted to format my computer and start fresh, so I did this, I noticed it took 6 hours to just get through the entire install, when I got into Windows 8, it was extremely slow so I formatted again.

I remembered that the last time I did a install I had to for some reason disconnect all my harddrives expect for 1(my ssd drive) and then the install took like 20mins.

I then plugged in all my other drives and noticed my computer was slow again(I would make a new folder on my desktop and I would have to hit F5 to refresh as it would not show up), then windows constantly want to repair my 1TB drive which took hours.

I am running the Western Digital Life Guard but it seems like it will fail(quick test says estimated time for test 2 mins been going for 10mins and when I try to do an erase it fails due to partition errors.)

I don't understand as the drive was working fine before the format as far as I could tell.

Comment: do your SMART stats indicate any mechanical issues? I read SMART stats in windows using Speedfan.

Comment: It seemed to pass the smart test or whatever but when I tried to do the quick test that would never finish.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of formatting your hard drive over, and over again, run chkdsk on it with the thorough option (5 stages instead of 3) this may take several hours depending on the size of the drive, and any errors that are found.

In Windows 8/8.1 use the following procedure:

1. Right click the bottom left corner of your screen, and choose Command Prompt (Admin). Allow it to run
2. type "chkdsk C: /r" Without the quotes, and press Enter. Replace C with your system drive letter.
3. When asked if you want to check the disk next time the computer restarts, press Y then enter.
4. Close the command prompt, and restart your computer.

the /r switch tells chkdsk (or scandisk if you will) to not only check the file system for errors, but to also check the physical surface of the disk for errors, or anomolies.

If this is an SSD drive, it is possible that it is near it's end of life. SSD drive, and FLASH media drives generally have a finite life cycle, and the more you use them, the quicker they will die.

If this doesn't resolve your issue, I'd highly suggest replacing the drive, or installing windows on either an IDE, or SATA drive.

Comment: My SSD drive with windows is fine, My Sata drive is not fine. I would like to run a check disk but since Windows does not even give it a drive letter I don't know how, For a while everytime I loaded windows 8 up, it would try to repair the drive for hours by next boot it would do the same thing again.